# emacs org-mode language of time stamps

Tags: date, emacs, org-mode

Depending on the computer I use, abbreviation for day names changes: it would be mon, tues, wed… on an american ubuntu and lun., mar., mer.… on a french ubuntu etc.

This is causing problem with the org-habit module of org-mode which stop working correctly when those format are mixed.

This localization is present even when I bypass my emacs configuration file using the `-Q` option.

How can I sort this out?

Comment: Looking through the org-mode source, it looks this is done using the variable `parse-time-weekdays`.  But the built-in `parse-time-string` also parses things like "Tuesday", so I don't know if setting `parse-time-weekdays` will do what you want.

Comment: It does not seem so. The values of `parse-time-weekdays` on the French ubuntu are in english.

Comment: If you change them to French, does that fix your problems org-habit?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
;; System locale to use for formatting time values.
(setq system-time-locale "C")         ; Make sure that the weekdays in the
                                      ; time stamps of your Org mode files and
                                      ; in the agenda appear in English.
```